# How to use CSS to move letters to the bottom of their divs

Tags: css, text-align

I have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/e9ozyj0w/

I want to have the letters `g`, `o`, `&nbsp;` and `n` aligned to the bottom of their divs and the completion `owhere` aligned to them.

How can I do this?  (I've already tried `vertical-align`, `text-align` and `bottom: 0`.)

P.S. A minimal reproducible example is:

html:

```
<div class="input">
  <div class="char">g</div>
  <div class="char">o</div>
  <div class="char">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="char">n</div>
  <div class="completions">
    <div>orth</div>
    <div>orthwards</div>
    <div>owhere</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

div.prefix {
    display: flex;

}

div.completion {
    position: relative;
}

div.char {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

It produces:

```
go north
    orthwards
    owhere
```

I would like:

```
    orth
    orthwards
go nowhere
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do? But i do some experiment kindly review:->https://codepen.io/jaydeeep/pen/QWWXvOj

Comment: @jaydeeppatel Thanks for helping, but I've just added what I want into the question.

Comment: Why would you split words like this? It's totally inaccessible and will damage your seo rankings as it won't have proper words to search for

Comment: @Pete It's a custom html input component, which needs to colour/style characters individually.  I'll probably group characters which have the same style.

Comment: So why wouldn't you just have the word and then wrap a span around the first letter and style that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to div.input:

```
align-items: flex-end;
```

Here is my go-to documentation on how to use flexbox: [CSS Tricks Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

One more solution it's easy you need to just add     `margin-top: auto;` into your `.char`.

Let me know further clarification

Hope it will help :)

```css
div.input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

div.prefix {
    display: flex;

}

div.completion {
    position: relative;
}

div.char {
    bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="input">
      <div class="char">g</div>
      <div class="char">o</div>
      <div class="char">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="char">n</div>
      <div class="completions">
        <div>orth</div>
        <div>orthwards</div>
        <div>owhere</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css code

```
div.input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

div.prefix {
    display: flex;

}

div.completion {
    position: relative;
}

.completions{
   display: flex;
}

div.char {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```